# get the host the user is coming from

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-host

i wanted to know in python how can i get the host the user came from?
how do i extract it?

i tried this:

```
host = self.request._environ['HTTP_HOST']
```

but it's empty...

Do you have any idea what it should be

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`self.request._environ['HTTP_HOST']` tells you *your* host name.

You can use `self.request.remote_addr` to get the remote IP address.  You'll need to do a reverse DNS lookup (which might fail) if you need a host name from that.

Comment: I want my hostname i want to search for a word in my host name... but it's empty

Comment: if i am only in local host it will work? it will be my hostname?